# Error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table in BackgroundServices

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, background-service

I have a method in BackgroundServices that successfully retrieves data from an API. But when saving the response data to dbContext, I get the error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Orders' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

```
    //In Program.cs    
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ConsumedScopeServiceHostedService>();
```

When I test the API in Postman and BackgroundServices is not used, SaveChangesAsync() works. Can someone please assist?

```
    public class ConsumedScopeServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
{

    public ConsumedScopeServiceHostedService
        (
            IServiceProvider services
        )
        {
            Services = services;
        }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    private readonly PeriodicTimer _importOrdersTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        while (await _importOrdersTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken) && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            await DoWorkAsync();         

        }
    }

        
    private async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            foreach (var item in newOrders)
            {
                scopedDbContext.Add(item);
            }
            scopedDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: This has error has nothing to do with the background service code. You are trying to add an explicit value to a column whose values are auto generated by your database. I guess that's the column you using as the primary key for your orders table.

Comment: Yes, that column is my primary key. If the error has nothing to do with background services why does it work perfectly when I access the same method through an API call?

Comment: @launchCode is the data being passed (for the PK) in both the scenarios same?

Comment: Your database has an identity column. But your EF Core model does not know that the database will generate a value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error. It was in how I was using ScopeServices. I refactored the method by removing using(var scope = Services.CreateScope()) statements and instantiated them like so at the top of the method using ScopeFactory. The OrderScopeService is used in another part of the method. But if you need to add multiple scope services this is an example.

```
            using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var OrderScopeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IOrder>();
            var DbContextScopeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();
```

I did not need to add this annotation to the entity key

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Final Edit

```
            using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var OrderScopeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IOrder>();
            var DbContextScopeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

                foreach (var item in newOrders)
                {
                  DbContextScopeService.Add(item);
                }
                DbContextScopeService.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, I think you are passing a value to the `Id`(the PK field) of the `Order`. If you have enabled identity and is auto-incrementing the value from the DB, you can't pass in the value of ID field for an 'insert' scenario.

If you do require the `Id` to be passed from code, you must enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` in the database by using the command
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON`

**EDIT**

Add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to the primary key column. Then try adding a transaction scope also as below

```
    using var transaction = scopedDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    scopedDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders ON;");
    foreach (var item in newOrders) 
    { 
        scopedDbContext.Add(item); 
    } 
    scopedDbContext.SaveChanges(); 
    scopedDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders OFF");
    transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: I have tried to SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON, but it still throws the same error.                             

var scopedDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders ON;");


foreach (var item in newOrders)
            {
                scopedDbContext.Add(item);
            }
            scopedDbContext.SaveChanges();


var scopedDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders OFF;");

Comment: Made an edit to the answer. Please see if it helps.

Comment: I did try your suggestions and the same error is occurring. In fact, the application shuts down when it tries to SaveChanges() (FYI, this was happening before also).  I have implemented a HttpClient that calls the API in place of the scoped content and it works great. The API has the same entities and code as the scoped content.